# Python websocket connect and listen to incoming messages

Tags: python, websocket, server, proxy, relay

I can't find a very simple example how to do websocket connect in python, and provide some on_message callback that listens to incoming messages.

So the websocket has `create_connection` method to create a connection, but I don't see where I can pass a callback function that will be called each time the other side send messages to me.

I am creating a simple python websocket proxy/relay, so every time a client is connected to my server, I want to create a connection to another server, and then listen to incoming messages so I can pass them back to the client.

Comment: 1. add some code. 2. which lib are you using? 3. the problem is with the client or with the server?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do it this way. I hope that's the optimal way to do so.

```
ws = create_connection(url)
def run(*args):
        while True:
            try:
                message = ws.recv() # This is blocking
            # do what I need to do here
            except WebSocketClosedError:
                break

    thread.start_new_thread(run, ())
```

Comment: Maybe you should explain your solution?

Comment: Another option is by using python Tornado